# C++ Pointer to byte array optimization

Tags: c++, windows, optimization, visual-studio-2013

I am currently using this approach to copy some byte values over:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (iLen + 1); i++)
    {
        *(pBuffer + i) = Image.pVid[i];
    }
```

I would like to ask if there is a way to copy these values over in one go, perhaps by using memcopy to gain more speed.

The entire code is:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall GetCameraImage(BYTE pBuffer[], int Type, int uWidth, int uHeight)
{
    CameraImage Image;

    int ret;

    Image.pVid = (unsigned int*)malloc(4 * uWidth*uHeight);
    ret = stGetCameraImage(&Image, 1, uWidth, uHeight);
    if (ret == ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        int iLen = (4 * uWidth * uHeight);

        for (int i = 0; i < (iLen + 1); i++)
        {
            *(pBuffer + i) = Image.pVid[i];
        }

        ////print(“ImageType = %d, width = %d, height = %d”, Image.Type, Image.Width,
        ////    Image.Height);
        ////print(“First Pixel : B = %d, G = %d, R = %d”, Image.pVid[0], Image.pVid[1],
        ////    Image.pVid[2]);
        ////print(“Second Pixel : B = %d, G = %d, R = %d”, Image.pVid[4], Image.pVid[5],
        ////    Image.pVid[6]);
    }

    free(Image.pVid);

    return ret;
}
```

Edit:
*pVid is this:

```
unsigned int *pVid;             // pointer to image data (Format RGB32...)
```

Comment: Are you sure about `i < (iLen + 1);` ?

Comment: Not really sure about it. Should it be i < iLen?

Comment: It is a bit unclear: do you want to copy byte-by-byte? In the other words, what is the size of the pBuffer: same number of items as in Image or same number of bytes?

Comment: Yes, should be `i < iLen`, I believe. First index would be `0`, last would be `iLen-1`, total of `iLen` items

Comment: Your current code is invalid. You are reading past the allocated size of the memory `pBlock` points to (by a factor of 4).

Comment: @AndrewMedico What would be the correct code? i < (iLen - 4) ?

Comment: Your existing code will only copy the lowest byte of each 4-byte unit into `pBuffer`. Is that definitely what you want?

Comment: also you never use the function parameter `Type`

Comment: @AndrewMedico it converts each `unsigned int` it reads into `byte` for storage (discarding 3/4 of the information)  , (in addition to reading too many unsigned ints as you say)

Comment: Looks like what you really want is a typecast, not a memory copy.  Something like : stGetCameraImage((int*)pBuffer, 1, uWidth, uHeight);  ... should populate the destination buffer, and then you can access it as bytes.  Done and done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is currently written, each assignment in your loop will overflow and give you some garbage value in `pBuffer` because you're trying to assign an `unsigned int` to a `BYTE`. On top of that, you will run off the end of the `Image.pVid` array because `i` is counting bytes, not `unsigned int`s

You could fix your code by doing this:

```
*(pBuffer + i) = ((BYTE*)Image.pVid)[i];
```

But that is pretty inefficient.  Better to move whole words at a time, or you could just use memcpy instead:

```
memcpy(pBuffer,Image.pVid,iLen)  //pBuffer must be at least iLen bytes long
```